# NoReverseMatch at Django when I tried to update model object

Tags: django

I am writing a view to update a record in the database, when I try to switch to a record for editing, I get an error:

**Error:**

[image]

I wrote one to one from an existing view for another model, so I do not understand what the error is. How i can fix this?

**urls.py**

```
 path(
    'keys/<int:key_id>/',
    views.UpdateKeyView.as_view(),
    name='update_key'
),
```

**views.py**

```
class CreateKeyView(
    SuccessMessageMixin,
    CustomPermissionRequired,
    CreateView
):

    model = ApiKey

    template_name = 'db_visual/create_key.html'

    form_class = KeyForm

    permission_required = (
        'db_visual.add_keys',
    )

    success_message = "Ключи %(description)s успешно создан!"

    def get_success_url(self):
        print(self.object.id)
        return reverse_lazy(
            'update_key',
            kwargs={'key_id': self.object.id}
        )


  class UpdateKeyView(
    SuccessMessageMixin,
    CustomPermissionRequired,
    UpdateView
):
    model = ApiKey
    pk_url_kwarg = 'key_id'

    template_name = 'db_visual/update_key.html'

    form_class = KeyForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('keys')

    permission_required = (
        'db_visual.change_key',
    )

    success_message = "Ключ <a href='%(url)s'>%(description)s</a> " \
                      "успешно изменен!"

    def get_success_message(self, cleaned_data):
        return self.success_message % dict(
            cleaned_data,
            url=reverse_lazy(
                'update_key',
                kwargs={'key_id': self.object.id}
            ),
        )
```

**HTML-code create_key**

```
{% for key in api_keys %}
        <tr>
            <td class="min-col">
            <a href="{% url 'update_key' key_id=key.id %}">
                    {{ key.description}}
            </a>
            </td>
            <td class="min-col">{{ key.open_key }}</td>
            <td class="min-col">{{ key.secret_key }}</td>
            <td class="min-col">
                <a class="btn btn-sm btn-link"
                   href="{% url 'update_key' key_id=key.id %}">
                    <i class="far fa-edit fa-lg"></i>
                </a>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

**HTML-code update_key**

```
<form action="{% url 'update_key' key_id=key.id %}"
      method="post" class="col-12" id="key_form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="card">
        <h2 class="card-header">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">
                    Ключи для {{ key.description }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </h2>
        <div class="card-body">
            {% include 'db_visual/key_form_body.html' %}
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer text-muted">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Сохранить"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Model.py**

```
class ApiKey(models.Model):
    open_key = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    secret_key = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    restrict_ip = models.BooleanField()
    ip = ArrayField(
        models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=False, null=True), size=8, blank=True, null=True
    )
    valid_to_date = models.DateField()
    restrict_methods = models.BooleanField()
    allowed_methods = ArrayField(
        models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True, null=True),
        size=8, blank=True, null=True
    )
    forbidden_methods = ArrayField(
        models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True, null=True),
        size=8, blank=True, null=True
    )

    class Meta:
        db_table = '"processing"."api_key"'
```

UPD: When i create new object and try to do function `get_success_url` it gets the same error, but `self.object.id` in not None.

UPD2: found out that the model object is not passed to `update_key`, but it is not clear why.

Comment: Are you sure _all_ off your `ApiKey` objects have `id`?

Comment: It looks to me that your key_id in the view contains an empty string - but the view is looking for an integer value, so it will not match.

Comment: @PedramParsian, yes I'm sure.

Comment: @ger.s.brett, can you help me to fix this?

Comment: Can you please add the code of the model?

Comment: Replace the <int:key_id> by <str:key_id> and make sure you convert the value to integer when you need it.

Comment: @ger.s.brett, I replaced, but still getting an error.

Comment: the same error?

Comment: @ger.s.brett yes

Comment: can you post it

Comment: @ger.s.brett, The error is shown at the beginning of the question.

Comment: it cannot be the same.

Comment: @ger.s.brett, The error is the same, just in case, I completely restarted the django, but the error does not change.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Error was in name of object...